# How to add share button for each item in hero card for facebook messenger - Bot framework c#

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, direct-line-botframework

I am working on a bot which will have a list of items in hero card. I have to add share button only for facebook. I am facing an issue if I have multiple cards with share options. Can you please provide me a solution how can I add share option for each item in hero card.

[Facebook Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/share/)

Comment: Please show some effort what have you tried. Share some code to start with.

Comment: You already provided a link explaining how to include share buttons in Messenger. What issue are you facing?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Hey Kyle, I am looking to add the share button for every item in the carousel. But I am able to add only one. In facebook documentation, it's mentioned that **"Maximum of one URL button on the template. If no buttons are specified, the buttons property on the generic template must be set to an empty array.**. 
". Can you help me is there any possibility??

Comment: You will have to provide some code that shows what you're currently doing

Comment: Are you still working on this?